# Single items are all in on XML field when using PHP SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, php, query, ideas

That's the snippet from it.

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Body, Status from Idea";
//print_r($query."</br>");
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
// QueryResult object is only for PARTNER client
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response); 

echo "<br />";
foreach($queryResult->records as $record) {
  echo "Text = ".$record->any."<br />";

}
```

If I `var_dump` the XML, all the queried data is in an `any` field:

```
{ [0]=> string(18) "087e0000000*******" [1]=> string(18) "087e0000000*******" } ["any"]=> string(81) "testidea2 asdadkawpodkqwdqNow Available" }
```

(also he get the title value `testidea2` and it is not queried)

The final relust after the foreach loop is:

```
Text = testidea2 asdadkawpodkqwdqNow Available
Text = testidea1 bliblablubNew
```

How can I get the the values `Status(Now Available)` and `Body(asdadkawpodkqwdqNow)` as separate items?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Edit: related github issue

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/issues/24#issuecomment-21172056

Answer (score 0):

Based on this closed issue:
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/issues/33

Looks like it was a bad sample on developer.force.com, which has now been updated.